# jquery ajax modify response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to replace the contents inside div with id = test with the modified AJAX response

javascript:

```
('.test').bind('ajax:success', function()
{
    $.ajax({
          success: function(html){
            $('.test').text($(html).find("#test"));  // returns [object Object]

          }
    });
});
```

But `$(html).find("#test")` returns an `[object Object]` and `$(html).find("#test").html()` returns `null`

How can I get the contents of div with id "test" in the ajax response?

Comment: How is the content of `html`?

Comment: it might be easier to just use `.load()` for what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this blog  [link](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/), the answer is in the second parameter:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // create a convenient toggleLoading function
  var toggleLoading = function() { $("#loading").toggle() };

  $("#tool-form")
    .bind("ajax:loading",  toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:complete", toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
      $("#response").html(data);
    });
});
```

Then, your code would be:

```
$('.test').bind('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {

   // this is $('.test')
   $(this).text($(data).find("#test"));

});
```